# PineScript: Multiple 'alert_message' on multiple 'strategy.exit'

Tags: json, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to give SignalStack a try. They need their commands relayed to them, through alerts, in JSON format and can only receive single commands -  that is I can only place either a buy or sell order, I cannot have TP and SL commands within in the same JSON alert.

The problem here, per TD's PineScript language, I can only have one 'strategy.exit' condition per "if" statement.

here is a snip of my simple entry and exist logic:

```
//Enter Bull position
if ta.crossover(Bull, Bear) and not na(Time) and strategy.opentrades <= 0
    strategy.entry("Bullish Entry", strategy.long, qty = CS)
    strategy.exit("Bullish Exit", "Bullish Entry", profit = 43, alert_message = "{JSON Command"})
    strategy.exit("Bullish Exit", "Bullish Entry", loss = 39, alert_message = "{JSON Command"})
    strategy.close("Bearish Entry")
//Enter Bear position
if ta.crossunder(Bull, Bear) and not na(Time) and strategy.opentrades <= 0
    strategy.entry("Bearish Entry", strategy.short, qty = CS) 
    strategy.exit("Bearish Exit", "Bearish Entry", profit = 43, alert_message = "{JSON Command"})
    strategy.exit("Bearish Exit", "Bearish Entry", loss = 39, alert_message = "{JSON Command"})
    strategy.close("Bullish Entry")
if na(Time)
    strategy.close_all("CLOSED FOR THE DAY")
```

Reading this, you should get the logic of what I am trying to affect here. but that second "strategy.exit" per "if" statement will not work. But in order to use SignalStacks automation services, I have to have the a JSON command per "buy" and "sell" alert.

Any help to my situation here would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your exits into one `strategy.exit()` and use dedicated exit alert messages.

> strategy.exit(id, from_entry, qty, qty_percent, profit, limit, loss,
> stop, trail_price, trail_points, trail_offset, oca_name, comment,
> comment_profit, comment_loss, comment_trailing, alert_message,
> **alert_profit**, **alert_loss**, alert_trailing) → void
>
> ***alert_profit (series string)*** Text that will replace the
> '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' placeholder when one is used in the
> "Message" field of the "Create Alert" dialog. Only replaces the text
> if the exit was triggered by crossing `profit` or `limit`
> specifically. Optional. The default is na.
>
> ***alert_loss (series string)*** Text that will replace the
> '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' placeholder when one is used in the
> "Message" field of the "Create Alert" dialog. Only replaces the text
> if the exit was triggered by crossing `stop` or `loss` specifically.
> Optional. The default is na.

It would look like:

```
strategy.exit("Bullish Exit", "Bullish Entry", profit = 43, loss = 39, alert_profit = "{JSON Command}", alert_loss = "{JSON Command}")
```

Comment: I can’t believe I missed that! Thank you so much!!